# Is CodeIgniter a better choice to use compared to Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently using Dreamweaver to run PHP codes.It involves extracting values from the database and most of the time it involves sensitive data. A friend suggested to use CodeIgniter as it has higher levels of security and more layers. What should I do? Should i continue using Dreamweaver or switch to CodeIgniter?

Comment: Did you look at CodeIgniter's website? How do you think that would be a replacement for Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are different. Dreamweaver is an editor whereas CI is a PHP framework.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter is a PHP framework. Dreamweaver is an IDE. You can use PHP, HTML , CSS , and ofcourse CodeIgniter library inside Dreamweaver.